# ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting `ElementNotVisibileException` but this page has no duplicate names with the name of "History" but it does have "Calls History". Can anyone suggest the best locator to locate element?

```
<li class="ui-widget ui-menuitem ui-corner-all ui-menu-parent" aria- haspopup="true" role="menuitem">
   <a class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="javascript:void(0)">
      <span class="ui-menuitem-text">History</span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
   </a>
```

The error

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)Command duration or timeout: 122 millisecondsBuild info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'System info: host: 'rsn-GA-78LMT-S2', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-54-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_101'Session ID: 17716ecc-ffe3-40f9-92a6-8a106acf478dDriver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>       Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true,javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, pplicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=38.0.1}]   atun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: Actions c_history1 = new Actions(obj);
  WebElement visbilityhc = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Visibility')]"));
  WebElement vhistoryc = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'History']"));
  WebElement vhcalls = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//span[(text() = 'Calls')]"));
  c_history1.moveToElement(visbilityhc).moveToElement(vhistoryc).moveToElement(vhcalls).click().build().perform();

Comment: If you have some extra details that you want to add after you originally post your question (like the code above), rather than add it as a comment go ahead and edit your question and add it there so it can be properly formatted and more easily found by future readers.

Comment: When you get the exception, `ElementNotVisibleException`, it means your element was found but it was not visible so it can't be interacted with. Selenium was designed to only interact with elements as a user would so since users can't interact with invisible elements, neither will Selenium. From your `Actions` code, it looks like you are having to hover several times and then click. Have you tried adding a break point and stepping through the code to see what happens? It might help you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `a` element which having text `History`, try using `linkText` with `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` to wait until element visible as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement linkElement= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("History")));
```

or if you want get `span` element which having text `History`, try using `xPath` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement spanElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'History']")));
```

**Edited** :- If this `element` getting visible with mouse over event try using `Action` to perform `MouseOver` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement spanElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'History']")));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);    
builder.moveToElement(spanElement).perform();
```

or

```
builder.mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)spanElement).coordinates)
```

Hope it will work..:)

Comment: Actually that is mouse over element, visibilit>History-->calls, so i need to use actions class ,so can you suggest

Comment: Actions c_history1 = new Actions(obj);WebElement visbilityhc = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Visibility')]"));
  WebElement vhistoryc = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'History']"));
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(obj, 2);
  WebElement spanElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'Calls']")));

  //WebElement vhcalls = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Calls')]"));
  c_history1.moveToElement(visbilityhc).moveToElement(vhistoryc).moveToElement(spanElement).click().build().perform();

Comment: Actions c_history1 = new Actions(obj);
  WebElement visbilityhc = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Visibility')]"));
  WebElement vhistoryc = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'History']"));
  WebElement vhcalls = obj.findElement(By.xpath("//span[(text() = 'Calls')]"));
  c_history1.moveToElement(visbilityhc).moveToElement(vhistoryc).moveToElement(vhcalls).click().build().perform();

Comment: @KumarUppu could you share your website URL where you want to automate that's why i could give you better solution..

Comment: @KumarUppu your second provided code looks like ok...is there any problem??